# Specialize template with function pointer, that depends on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I would like to have a template with a nested value which should be initialized by a given initializer function:

```
template <typename T, T(INIT)()> struct Foo
{
    T value = INIT();
};
```

It can be used this way:

```
// Some random type only instanceable through factory()
struct Bar
{
    int bar{};
private:
    // The only way to create a Bar is through factory()
    friend Bar factory();
    Bar() {};
};

Bar factory() { return {}; }

Foo<Bar, factory> foo;
```

But, if no function is provided, the template should try to default-initialize the nested value, so I've tried to specialize the template:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo<T, nullptr>
{
    T value{};
};
```

The idea is to use it this way:

```
struct Baz{};

Foo<Bar, factory> foo; // Nested Bar have Bar::bar initialized through factory function.
Foo<Baz>          baz; // No factory function needed, nested Baz default-initialized.
```

But I just discovered that template partial specialization types cannot rely on other template types, the error I'm getting is pasted below:

> error: type 'T (*)()' of template argument 'nullptr' depends on a template parameter
>    template  struct Foo

---

Is there a way to achieve my goal? It would be nice if it works with template variables as well:

```
template <typename T, T(INIT)()> T Foo = INIT();
template <typename T>            T Foo<T, nullptr>{};
```

Extra question: Why partial specializations cannot depend on template parameters? What's the rationale behind this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only about doing a default initialization if the second template parameter is missing, you may provide a templated default initialization function as the default parameter like.

```
template<typename T> 
    T do_default_assign() { 
        return T(); 
    };                                                                      

template <typename T, T (INIT)() = do_default_assign<T> > struct Foo 
    { 
        T value = INIT(); 
    };
```

This however suffers an unnecessary "return by value" and assignment operation which might be costly or impossible for some T.

Comment: Accepted this one and no the one from @Jarod42 because it was answered 1 second before!

Answer (score 3):

For your case, you may use:

```
template <typename T>
T default_construct() { return T{}; }

template <typename T, T(INIT)() = &default_construct<T>>
struct Foo
{
    T value = INIT();
};
```

And then use it like:

```
Foo<int> f;
Foo<int, bar> b;
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/3j3veQ)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `constructor` template function that will initialize a value of type `Type` and then use it as a default constructor:

```
template<typename Type, typename... Args>
Type constructor(Args... args) { 
    return Type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

and then use it as default template argument for the function:

```
template <typename T, T(INIT)() = constructor<T>> struct Foo
{
    T value = INIT();
};
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86924ac2a86cfd4e)

Comment: This approach looks great because it allows to pass any parameter to the constructor, but providing a `constructor` uncompatible with `T(INIT)()` isn't possible so in the end: forwarding all the `Args` to `constructor` doesn't make sense :(

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster True, but now you have a more general `constructor` which is a useful function that works on any constructor of any type (for other purposes), instead of an hard coded `default_construct` or `do_default_assign` as other have proposed.